# Where to Break the Chain with Task, ContinueWith, Lock

Tags: c#, .net, locking, task, mvp

I have MVP application C#, .NET 4, WinForms. It uses Bridge class which communicate with third party app via NamedPipe.
The command flow is like this:  View → Presenter  → Manager → Bridge → Client
And back in the reverse order. View is prepared for multitasking. I split reverse chain in Manager by rising event with the result, but it doesn't help.

```
// View class
public void AccountInfo_Clicked() { presenter.RequestAccountInfo(); }

public void UpdateAccountInfo(AccountInfo info)
{
    if (pnlInfo.InvokeRequired)
        pnlInfo.BeginInvoke(new InfoDelegate(UpdateAccountInfo), new object[] {info});
    else
        pnlInfo.Update(info);
}

// Presenter class
public void RequestAccountInfo() { manager.RequestAccountInfo(); }

private void Manager_AccountInfoUpdated(object sender, AccountInfoEventArgs e)
{
    view.UpdateAccountInfo(e.AccountInfo);
}

// Manager class
public void RequestAccountInfo()
{
    AccountInfo accountInfo = bridge.GetAccountInfo();
    OnAccountInfoUpdated(new AccountInfoEventArgs(accountInfo));
}

// Bridge class
public AccountInfo GetAccountInfo() { return client.GetAccountInfo(); }

// Client class
public AccountInfo GetAccountInfo()
{
    string respond = Command("AccountInfo");
    return new AccountInfo(respond);
}

private string Command(string command)
{
    var pipe = new ClientPipe(pipeName);
    pipe.Connect();
    return pipe.Command(command);
}
```

I want to unfreeze the UI during command processing. There are also other commands that can be executed. Finally all commands reach `Command(string command)` method in Client.

I tried to break the chain in Manager by using task and ContinueWith but it results to pipe failing to connect. The reason is that client is not thread safe.

```
// Manager class
public void RequestAccountInfo()
{
    var task = Task<AccountInfo>.Factory.StartNew(() => bridge.GetAccountInfo());
    task.ContinueWith(t => { OnAccountInfoUpdated(new AccountInfoEventArgs(t.Result)); });
}
```

My question is: Where to use Task, ContinueWith and where to Lock?

I assume I can lock only `Command(string command)` because it is the ultimate method.

```
private string Command(string command)
{
    lock (pipeLock)
    {
        var pipe = new ClientPipe(pipeName);
        pipe.Connect();
        return pipe.Command(command);
    }
}
```

Can I use Task, Wait in `Command` in Client class?

Comment: so your application should be async all the way ?

Comment: Yes I hope. There are 5-10 views that can be opened. Each of them has own copy of Bridge and respectively Client. Also there are 5-6 commands that can be given from each View. All this have to be send to other thread somewhere. But I don't know where in the command chain. And also where in chain to lock.

Comment: What error is being thrown when using `Task`?

Comment: "Pipe is busy" from `pipe.Connect()` I think. I assume that other commands are reaching `Command(string command)` while pipe is waiting for respond form the other side.

Comment: The exact error is 231 ERROR_PIPE_BUSY, thrown by ` handle = NamedPipeNative.CreateFile(...)` in NamedPipe class `Connect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I locked `Command` in Client class. It appears that it works perfectly in that way. No blocking UI, no pipe errors. I lock on `pipeName` because each copy of View is using a unique pipe name.

I applied `Task<Type>`, `ContinueWith` to all commands in `Manager` class.

```
// Manager class
public void RequestSomeInfo()
{
    var task = Task<SomeInfo>.Factory.StartNew(() => bridge.GetSomeInfo());
    task.ContinueWith(t => { OnInfoUpdated(new InfoEventArgs(t.Result)); });
}

// Client class
private string Command(string command)
{
    lock (pipeName)
    {
        var pipe = new ClientPipe(pipeName);
        pipe.Connect();
        return pipe.Command(command);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having is that `bridge.GetAccountInfo()` is trying to extract information from the UI itself - hence the UI thread. This code

```
public void RequestAccountInfo()
{
    var task = Task<AccountInfo>.Factory.StartNew(() => bridge.GetAccountInfo());
    task.ContinueWith(t => { OnAccountInfoUpdated(new AccountInfoEventArgs(t.Result)); });
}
```

is attempting to execute the `bridge.GetAccountInfo()` method (accessing the UI) from a background thread-pool thread.

My first question here would be how expensive is the call to `bridge.GetAccountInfo()`? If it is not expensive, it makes no sense to put working into multi-threading this aspect. If it is expensive, you will have to think about a way to make this operation thread safe (I can't advise without more information).

Another thing to do would assess the expense of a move to WCF. This handles most synchronisation problems for you... I am sorry I can't be of more help. I wrote the above before I read your last comment.

I hope this is of some use.

---

Aside: something to be aware of is [`SynchronizationContext`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I). Using a `TaskScheduler` you can launch a `Task` on the UI thread (this is not what you want here as this again will just block the UI - however, this can be good to know when reporting [in .NET 4.0]. To launch your code above on the UI thread you can do

```
public void RequestAccountInfo()
{
    var task = Task<AccountInfo>.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        bridge.GetAccountInfo(), 
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    task.ContinueWith(t => { OnAccountInfoUpdated(new AccountInfoEventArgs(t.Result)); });
}
```

Comment: "How expensive is the call to bridge.GetAccountInfo()?" It's not max 1 second. I was trying to do it hoping that using multitasking will free UI for executing more important automatic commands to Bridge. But now a start realizing that this is nonsense. I must lock somewhere because the pipe can execute only one command at a time. So event with tasking this AccountInfo command can (and will) block the other commands because of the nature of pipes.

Comment: "move to WCF". This is a no go at the moment. I'm not familiar with that technology. The Bridge was written from other programmer on hire and it uses unmanaged C++ dll on the other side of the pipe. The other app I communicate with cannot import .NET dlls.